# How do I use Spring Data Neo4j to persist a Map (java.util.Map) object inside an NodeEntity?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I need to save an  `Map<Object,List<Object>>` when i populated the containing class the node gets saved but the Map is not.

Here is the code I am using for the entity

```
    @NodeEntity
    public class UserAlias{
        @GraphId
        private Long id;

        @Fetch
        private Map<IdentityType,List<Permission>> aliases;

        private String name;

    }
......
    userAliasRepo.save(userAlias)
```

`IdentityType` is an Enum and `Permission` is a another Class not annotated with `@NodeEntity` and 
    `userAliasRepo` extends `GraphRepository`<>

So How can I persist the Map,I am Spring Data Neo4j version 3.3.0.RELEASE

What i want to achieve is to relate the following json to the UserAlias NodeEntity

```
{
    "name": "Bond",
    "permissions": {
        "Level5Acess": {
            "READ": false,
            "WRITE": false,
            "CREATE": false,
            "DEL": true
        },
        "Level4Acess": {
            "READ": false,
            "WRITE": false,
            "CREATE": false,
            "DEL": true
        },
        "Level1Acess": {
            "READ": true,
            "WRITE": true,
            "CREATE": true,
            "DEL": true
        },
        "Level0Acess": {
            "READ": true,
            "WRITE": true,
            "CREATE": true,
            "DEL": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @frant.hartm specified

> Other collection types than Set are not supported so far, also
>   currently NO Map>.

But `org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DynamicProperties` can be used instead of the Map which is then mapped to node-attributes.The only tradeoff is that this only supports primitive dataTypes and their corressponding array.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person {
    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;

    private DynamicProperties personalProperties;
    public void setProperty(String key, Object value) {
        personalProperties.setProperty(key, value);
    }

    public Object getProperty(String key) {
        return personalProperties.getProperty(key);
    }
}
@Test
    public void testCreateOutsideTransaction() {
        Person p = new Person("James", 35);
        p.setProperty("s", "String");
        p.setProperty("x", 100);
        p.setProperty("pi", 3.1415);
        persist(p);
        assertEquals(3, IteratorUtil.count(p.getPersonalProperties().getPropertyKeys()));
        assertProperties(nodeFor(p));
        p.setProperty("s", "String two");
        persist(p);
        assertEquals("String two", nodeFor(p).getProperty("personalProperties-s"));
    }
```

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/117145-spring-data-neo4j-how-to-map-java-util-map-string-string-field

Comment: `DynamicProperties` doesn't exist anymore on Spring Data Neo4j 4.x. Is there any workaround or new practice to map dynamic attributes to nodes on Neo4j?

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan As an alternative, you could serialize the data to a string, or graph the Map as a graph pattern itself. For large data though, you are much better saving it to some file store, and only keeping a reference to it in Neo4j (large property values degrade the database).

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in 3.x versions:

> Other collection types than Set are not supported so far, also currently NO `Map<RelationshipType,Set<NodeBacked>>`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming_model_relationships_relatedto

Comment: So any alternatives ?

Comment: Depends what graph model you want to achieve. One possibility would be to have Set<IdentityType> where IdentityType would be relationship entity.